# WAI Accessibility: How to fix AX_FOCUS_01 (These elements are focusable but either invisible or obscured by another element)

Tags: css, accessibility, wai-aria

I recently encountered an issue regarding web accessibility. I have a CSS that intentionally hides the original checkbox and replace it with a designed checkbox control. I understand that the issue is hiding the checkbox by css:outline and z-index, but I need those implementation while still implementing web accessibility. How can I do that?

EDIT:
Upon further checking, the error comes from the checkbox being hidden and replaced with CSS checkbox while the hidden checkbox is still focusable using keyboard (tabbing).

Comment: Have you tried hiding them by moving them off screen (e.g. negative x coordinates)?

Answer (score 2):

One technique that I found works well is clipping:

```
.hidden-clip {
    position: absolute;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
}
```

The hidden element is there in the document flow, it has dimensions and participates in the tab order, etc. It's just not really visible.

Comment: I tried using this, but it doesn't seem to solved the focusable issue. I placed it in the hidden checkbox.

Comment: Nevermind. I already fixed it. The issue is not being the hidden checkbox but because of a pathetic implementation of html. The checkbox and it's text (in <span>) is surrounded by <label> instead of using "for" attribute.

ex. 
<label><input type="checkbox"><span>Test</span></label>

instead of

<input id="test1" type="checkbox">
<label for="test1">Test1</label>